# Ubuntu Wi-fi driver not working on my Acer Aspire V15 Nitro?? (Qualcomm Atheros QC6174a

Tags: wireless, 16.04, acer

How do I install my wifi drivers? There is no option to "Enable Wi-fi" on my toolbar except for "Enable Networking".

Any help would be appreciated,.

Thanks.

Comment: Please open terminal and enter `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info`  Then paste the contents of the wireless-info.txt file at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL.  You shouldn't need a driver or backports as the 16.04 kernel supports most of the newer Qualcomm chipsets, it just lacks firmware

Comment: Do the logs hold any clues? Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `dmesg | grep ath`

Answer (score 2):

You likely need firmware that is not yet part of Ubuntu package linux-firmware

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp ath10k-firmware/ /lib/firmware/ath10k/
```

Reboot